# Named constants in ACSL specifications

Tags: frama-c

How can I make use of named constants in ACSL specifications? These constants are either Macros (`#define MY_CONST ...`) or constant declarations (`const int MY_CONST ...`). The former does not work since the macros are not expanded by the preprocessor (ACSL specs are C comments), the latter does not because the constants are treated as variables so that some proofs fail. The specification works fine if I replace the named constants with the actual numbers.

Does anyone have a good idea to handle named constants?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

In order to expand macros in ACSL specification, you can use the `-pp-annot` option.

Comment: I have tried this but got an error "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:1:[kernel] user error: unexpected token '/'" even when running "frama-c -cpp-extra-args="-I /usr/share/frama-c/libc -nostdinc" -pp-annot <source file>"

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve the problem with assistance of Pascal Cuoq. It is actually not a problem with frama-c but with gcc. One needs the -fpreprocessed compiler option. My complete command is now:

```
frama-c -cpp-extra-args="-I `frama-c -print-share-path`/libc" -cpp-extra-args="-nostdinc" -cpp-extra-args="-fpreprocessed </path/to/stdc-predef.h>" -wp -wp-rte -pp-annot myfile.c
```